# Keypress is interfering with canv.onmousedown();

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to do two different actions when the canvas is clicked and when a key is pressed, but it seems like both can't be done at the same time. Is there a way to do this even if the functions are completely unrelated?

```
canv.onmousedown = function() {
console.log("Hello World");
};
```

And for keypress...

```
if(rightPressed && heroX < canvas.width) {
        heroX += heroSpeed;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with single function. Listen for `click` event on canvas and check if it goes along with, for example shift being pressed.

```
    function(e) {
      if(!e.shiftKey) return; //it will do nothing unless shift key was pressed
    }
```

You can do it for any button with `e.keyCode` property. For example `e.keyCode === 32` would check if spacebar was pressed during the event. You can check any keyCode [here](http://keycode.info/).

Comment: Thanks! I will try this

Comment: Please mark my answer as solution if it helps you :)

Comment: I have to wait a few minutes before I can select it as an answer

Comment: I'd appreciate it! Glad i could help and happy coding!

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't fully solve the problem. When key is pressed, the click event doesn't occur.

Comment: I must have had a bug elsewhere that somehow got fixed

Comment: It was the computer I was using. However, it works with the external mouse. =)